# Load dynamically load page after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a some html in my app which is loaded dynamically. Here is fragment of relating html and jquery code:
main.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="navbar span2">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="active span2" id="statistics">Статистика</li>
            <li class="span2" id="LPU">ЛПУ</li> 
            <li class="span2" id="content">Состав</li>
            <li class="span2" id="add">Добавить</li>
            <li class="span2" id="addParticipant">Участника</li>
            <li class="span2" id="addLPU">ЛПУ</li>
            <li class="span2" id="addAdmin">Администратора</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainContent" class="span9">
    </div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mainContent").load("statistics.html");
}).on("click","ul.nav-stacked> li", function(){
        if($(this).attr("id")!="add"){
            if($(this).attr("class")!="active"){
                $("ul.nav-stacked li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                var contentForLoad=$(this).attr("id")+".html";
                $("#mainContent").load(contentForLoad);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(($(this).attr("class")!="active")&&($("#addParticipant").attr("class")!="active")&&($("#addLPU").attr("class")!="active")){
                $("ul.nav-stacked li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $("#addParticipant").css("opacity","1");
                $("#addLPU").css("opacity","1");
                $("#addAdmin").css("opacity","1");
            }
            else{
                $("ul.nav-stacked li").removeClass("active");
                $("#addParticipant").css("opacity","0");
                $("#addLPU").css("opacity","0");
                $("#addAdmin").css("opacity","0");
            }
        }
});
```

Next I on click on ".deleteParticipant" button I should refresh page and load in #mainContent the same content that was loaded. What is the best way to do what I need?

```
.on("click", ".deleteParticipant", function() {
    var id={id:$(this).parent().parent().find('td#idOfParticipant').html()};
    $.ajax({
        url:"delete.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: id,
        async: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    location.reload();
```

Comment: call location.reload() in success function

Comment: or load content using jquery in conatiner, add this line in success function:  $("#mainContent").load("statistics.html");

Answer (score 0):

Put "history.go(0)" in the delete button you wrote.

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Delete/Refresh">
```

Hope it Helps :)